# Echo but retain double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, echo

I'm trying to create a script which will echo varibles / text to a file - a snippet of this script is:

```
echo "
SUBJECT="Text here"
EMAIL="email@domain.co.uk"
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
" > /root/email.txt
```

This is working fine but all of the double quotes are being removed.

Current output:

```
# cat /root/email.txt
SUBJECT=Text here
EMAIL=email@domain.co.uk
EMAILMESSAGE=/tmp/emailmessage.txt
```

Desired output:

```
# cat /root/email.txt
SUBJECT="Text here"
EMAIL="email@domain.co.uk"
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Double quotes don't nest. Use single quotes:

```
echo '
SUBJECT="Text here"
EMAIL="email@domain.co.uk"
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
' > /root/email.txt
```

But this will add empty lines to the top and bottom of the file. If you don't want those:

```
echo 'SUBJECT="Text here"
EMAIL="email@domain.co.uk"
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"' > /root/email.txt
```

Probably a cleaner solution is to use a ["here document"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents)

```
cat > email.txt <<'EOF'
SUBJECT="Text here"
EMAIL="email@domain.co.uk"
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"
EOF
```

Comment: The nice thing about the here document is that it will still variable expansion where single quotes won't. One thing you didn't mention is escaping the quotes with a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

escaping double quotes will work

```
echo "a\"" 
output -> a"
```

try this:

```
echo "
SUBJECT=\"Text here\"
EMAIL=\"email@domain.co.uk\"
EMAILMESSAGE=\"/tmp/emailmessage.txt\"
" > /root/email.txt
```