# Shellscript Echo Print Out

Tags: shell, unix

How can I print out this: A "B" C. 
I use: `echo A "B" C` it will print out A B C but I want "B" not B. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print double quotes in shell programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929149/print-double-quotes-in-shell-programming)

Comment: and [Echo but retain double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15930323/3266847)

Answer (score 1):

Try printing like this `echo A \"B\" C`

Answer (score 1):

try printing it like this .

```
echo 'A "B" C'
```